# How to take yesterday's total int in comparison to today's int using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm not very familiar with SQL.

I use MS SQL.

I have 3 tables, which relates to each one as one to many. Mean for one History have many Applications, but for one Application have many ApplicationAttributes.

I need to show EnrollTotalYesterday column in Histories request for each History's Application, where name LIKE = '%Enrollment%'.

Please can anybody help me?

Histories table:

```
Id  Imei                  CreationDate   DeviceId
1   ProductionDevice299   2018-11-04     1
7   ProductionDevice299   2018-11-05     1
```

Applications table:

```
Id  Name              DeviceHistoryId
1   Enrollment.cone   1
2   DPC_OWNERS        1
3   OTHER_APPS        1
6   Enrollment.emp    7
7   DPC_OWNERS        7
```

ApplicationAttributes table:

```
Id  Key             Value   DeviceApplicationId
1   EnrolledTotal   2       1
2   LoginsTotal     5       2
3   OtherAttribt1   8       3
4   OtherAttribt2   12      3
5   OtherAttribt3   17      3
6   EnrolledTotal   21      6
7   LoginsTotal     25      7
```

Expected result:

```
Id  Imei                CreationDate DeviceId EnrollTotalToday EnrollTotalYesterday
1   ProductionDevice299 2018-11-04   1        2                0
7   ProductionDevice299 2018-11-05   1        21               2
```

My current sql query:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [id], 
    [Extent1].[Imei] AS [imei], 
    CAST([Extent1].[CreationDate] AS DATE) AS [lastSeenOnline],  
    [Extent1].[DeviceId] AS [deviceId],
    SUM(CAST([Extent4].[Value] AS BIGINT)) as [enrolledTotalToday]

    FROM [DeviceManagement].[dbo].[DeviceHistory] AS [Extent1]

    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT [Imei], max([CreationDate]) as MaxDate
        FROM [dbo].[DeviceHistory]
        GROUP BY [Imei], CAST([CreationDate] AS DATE)
    ) [Extent2] on [Extent1].[Imei] = [Extent2].[Imei] and [Extent1].[CreationDate] = [Extent2].MaxDate

    JOIN
     [DeviceManagement].[dbo].[DeviceApplication] AS [Extent3]
     ON [Extent3].DeviceHistoryId = [Extent1].id 
        JOIN
        [DeviceManagement].[dbo].[DeviceApplicationAttribute] [Extent4]
        on [Extent4].DeviceApplicationId = [Extent3].id and [Extent4].[Key] = 'EnrolledTotal'
    GROUP BY [Extent1].Id, [Extent1].Imei, [Extent1].CreationDate, [Extent1].DeviceId
```

Comment: What's your SQL Server release? Does it support `LAG` (2012+)?

Comment: @dnoeth MS SQL 13

Comment: There's no 2013, only 2102 or 2014.

Comment: @dnoeth latest one, then 2014

Comment: What if there were no enrollments today?

Comment: @James then just need to take latest one. Dnoeth's answer support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple task if you got SQL Server 2012+:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [id], 
    [Extent1].[Imei] AS [imei], 
    CAST([Extent1].[CreationDate] AS DATE) AS [lastSeenOnline],  
    [Extent1].[DeviceId] AS [deviceId],
    SUM(CAST([Extent4].[Value] AS BIGINT)) as [enrolledTotalToday],

 -- simply add a LAG to get the previous row's value
    LAG(SUM(CAST(Extent4.Value AS BIGINT)), 1, 0)  -- previous row, default 0
    OVER (PARTITION BY Imei --???    
          ORDER BY CreationDate ) AS EnrollTotalYesterday

    FROM [DeviceManagement].[dbo].[DeviceHistory] AS [Extent1]

    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT [Imei], max([CreationDate]) as MaxDate
        FROM [dbo].[DeviceHistory]
        GROUP BY [Imei], CAST([CreationDate] AS DATE)
    ) [Extent2] on [Extent1].[Imei] = [Extent2].[Imei] and [Extent1].[CreationDate] = [Extent2].MaxDate

    JOIN
     [DeviceManagement].[dbo].[DeviceApplication] AS [Extent3]
     ON [Extent3].DeviceHistoryId = [Extent1].id 
        JOIN
        [DeviceManagement].[dbo].[DeviceApplicationAttribute] [Extent4]
        on [Extent4].DeviceApplicationId = [Extent3].id and [Extent4].[Key] = 'EnrolledTotal'
    GROUP BY [Extent1].Id, [Extent1].Imei, [Extent1].CreationDate, [Extent1].DeviceId
```

Btw, don't you think it's easier to read without all those square brackets `[...]`? You should only add them when actually needed (and then may better Standard SQL double quotes `"..."`).

And aliasing every table as `Extentn` is similar to `tn` or `a`, `b`, `c`, it's hard to correlate it to the table name. And if you remove a table you got a gap in the numbering :-) You should use an abbreviation of the table name like `DeviceHistory as Hist`, `DeviceApplication as Appl`, etc.

Comment: Great, it works. Thank you a lot. [Extent] I use because of linqToSql habit. And [...] I use because of I like this brackets :)